# debugging program that crashes in pythonw but not in python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, pythonw

I have the following program.  When I run it with pythonw to suppress the console, it will run for ~40 seconds then close.  However, when I run it with python and the console open so I can catch errors, it runs until I shut it down.  I'm not sure why it is behaving this way, or how to debug it.  The program is below.

motion detector.pyw

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time, os, Tkinter,threading, thread
from Tkinter import *



class stuff:

    rectime=0
    delay=0
    kill=0

def getter():
    try:
        stuff.rectime=int(e.get())
        stuff.delay=int(e2.get())
    except ValueError:
        if stuff.rectime==0:
            stuff.rectime=int(15)
        if stuff.delay==0:
            stuff.delay=int(10)
    box.destroy()


def hello(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print "Hello"

def preview():

    s, img = cap.read()
    while True:
        cv2.imshow('Preview', img)
        s, img=cap.read()
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if k == 27 or stuff.kill==1:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            stuff.kill=0
            break

def mbox():
    def closewindow():
        Messagebox.destroy()
        stuff.kill=1


    Messagebox=Tk()
    Messagebox.wm_title("Info")
    l3=Label(Messagebox, text="This is your preview!  Align camera then press Okay or Enter start")
    b3=Button(Messagebox, text="Okay", command=closewindow)
    l3.grid(row=1,column=1)
    b3.grid(row=2,column=1)
    b3.bind('<Return>', lambda _: closewindow())
    Messagebox.after(4, lambda: Messagebox.focus_force())
    b3.focus_set()
    Messagebox.mainloop()


def mbox2():
    def closewindow():
        Messagebox.destroy()
        stuff.kill=1


    Messagebox=Tk()
    Messagebox.wm_title("Info")
    l3=Label(Messagebox, text="Press Okay to End Program")
    b3=Button(Messagebox, text="Okay", command=closewindow)
    l3.grid(row=1,column=1)
    b3.grid(row=2,column=1)
    b3.bind('<Return>', lambda _: closewindow())
    Messagebox.after(4, lambda: Messagebox.focus_force())
    b3.focus_set()
    Messagebox.iconify()
    Messagebox.mainloop()

box=Tk()
box.wm_title("Program Details")
e=Entry(box,bd=3)
e2=Entry(box,bd=3)
b=Button(box, text="Enter",command=getter)
l=Label(box,text="Record Time",justify=CENTER)
l2=Label(box,text="Prog. Delay",justify=CENTER)
l.grid(row=1,column=1)
e.grid(row=1,column=2)
l2.grid(row=2,column=1)
e2.grid(row=2,column=2)
b.grid(row=3,column=2)
e.focus_set()
b.bind('<Return>', lambda _: getter())
box.mainloop()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:\motion\\output.avi',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('F','M','P','4'), 30, (640,480),True)

threads = []
#h=threading.Thread(target=hello(5))


thread.start_new_thread(preview, ())
time.sleep(1)
#thread.start_new_thread(mbox, ())
mbox()

time.sleep(1)
for i in range(stuff.delay):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "program will start in", stuff.delay-i,'seconds','\r',
print "\nStarting"

thread.start_new_thread(mbox2, ())



fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
ctime=time.time()
ptime=time.time()
value=0

while True:
    if out.isOpened() is False:
        out.open('C:\motion\\output.avi',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'FMP4'),30,(640,480),True)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    out.write(frame)

    if time.time()>ctime+2:
        fgbg=cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        ctime=time.time()
    value=cv2.countNonZero(fgmask)
    print value,'\r',

    if value > 100:
        print "\n"
        movement=time.time()
        while time.time()<int(movement)+stuff.rectime:
            out.write(frame)
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            print int(time.time())-int(movement),'\r',


        if out.isOpened() is True:
            out.release()
        print "video captured" + time.strftime('%m/%d/%y at %H:%M:%S')
        os.rename('C:\motion\\output.avi','c:\motion\\' + time.strftime('%m-%d-%y_%H-%M-%S') + '.avi')

    if time.time()>int(ptime)+stuff.rectime:
        ptime=time.time()
        out.release()

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27 or stuff.kill==1:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: When you run it from the console is any output or are any errors ever displayed?

Comment: Your prints might be causing an unintentional synchronization when you run as console.  Try commenting those out and running on the console to see what happens.

Comment: Catch all exceptions and write them to a log.

Comment: @Dave76 The print commands appeared to be the problem.  Once I made them into comments the program ran all night without incident.  Thanks.  I